# ASP.NET launch debugging under an existing IIS URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-10

In ASP.NET <= 4.6.1 I was able to just point the IIS root to the Web project and when I started debugging and set the URL, which I have specified in IIS, i could simply debug in VS on the URL which has been used on the IIS. With ASP.NET 5 I can't find any way to do this. It looks like I have to launch it under a unused Port and Url. Is there any way to get it working like in <= 4.6.1

For example in <= 4.6.1 I had the following:

- IIS Site which was configured with the URL www.testapp.local and the physical path was set to the Web project of my ASP.NET solution
- In the web project properties I selected under the option "Web" -> "Servers" local IIS and specified as Project URL the same URL, which I had set in the IIS as Host

Answer (score -1):

Okay after googling for different keywords I found out, that this is currently not yet implememted. But it semms, there is a workaround for this currently: https://github.com/tuespetre/dnx-watch-iis/blob/master/README.md